# Filter and Map versus Reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, runtime, big-o

I am having trouble understanding the performance difference between doing a combination of a filter then a map on the filtered list compared to just iterating over the list once and doing a reduce.

In terms of the joint filter and map I see that we would have to iterate twice over a list. The first time to filter and then we iterate over the shorter filtered list. However, **overall** this should still be an O(n) operation, correct?

For the reduce operation the only difference I see in terms of runtime is that we only have to iterate over the list **once** and we can do the filtering and mapping all in one go.

But in either case shouldn't the run time still be O(n)? How are they different in terms of runtime performance?

Comment: What makes you think that their time complexities are different? Anyhow, it's a strange comparison, because filter & map cannot replace the reduce function.

Comment: Well there is a performance trade off and Im wondering what it is. Filter and map can be used instead of a single reduce. For example if you have an array and you would like to filter out negative values and then create an object with the integer as one of the values. In this way we could reduce with an empty array and use an if statement followed by adding to the array an object having the integer value as one of its properties

Comment: No, filter and map can't in general replace a single call to reduce. But a call to reduce can always replace any sequence of calls to filter and map. Complexity-wise, they are all O(n), where the unit here is the number of steps.